# An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll : Access to the path ... is denied

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file-io

I am trying to write a file to a directory that exists and is created by me in `G:\\` i.e. `not a system directory or in root drive` like this

```
File.WriteAllBytes(directoryPath.Replace("wav", "mp3"), asBytesArray);
```

But this is throwing me this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll    
Additional information: Access to the path 'G:\Song' is denied.
```

How can i solve this issue? Please help!

**This is coming while I am debugging from `Visual Studio` and i am not sure how to give administrative rights to the application which is being run as a debug**

Comment: Does the program actually run as you? Because apparently it does not have access to `G:\Song`, so either it runs as someone else or you too do not have access.

Comment: This is coming while I am debugging from `Visual Studio` logged in with my account.I am not sure how to give administrative rights to the application which is being run as a debug

Comment: Clearly you are using the wrong file name, it must be `@"G:\Song\mumble.mp3`

Comment: I am guessing that the `directoryPath` variable is not what you think it is.  Can you add more code?

Answer (score 3):

This usually means that either there is a **folder** named "G:\Song", so you can't replace a directory with a file, or that your windows user account doesn't have **permission** to write to that drive.

Right-click on the drive and look at security permissions to be sure you have permission.  Also, make sure the drive is not readonly, as in the case of a write-protected SD card or flash drive.

Comment: I can write or do anything using windows explorer, this is while running from VS.

Comment: You can run Visual Studio with Administrative Rights.  (Assuming Windows7, Right-click on Visual Studio icon in the start menu and click "Run as Administrator")

Comment: Having a similar issue, running VS as admin didn't do it for me : /

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and stumbled across this thread looking for an answer to another issue I am having.

But you issue sounds similar to one I had a few weeks ago, and the issue was that **SYSTEM** needed to also have Full Control over the folder.

May or may not be the issue, but mentioned incase it solves your or someone else's similar issue to what I experienced.