# Ignore files while copying

Tags: vb.net

So i have an array of locations named `locations` and a destination variable named `copyTO`.

Here is my code:

```
        For Each locat In locations

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(locat, copyTO, True)

        Next
```

When i try to copy files that i dont have permissions or are being used, the aplication crashes.

How can i ignore those files and copy the rest?

I tryed google and i didnt find any awnser to this problem...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your application is encountering an error and doesn't know what to do with the exception. If you do a Try..Catch..End Catch you can choose how you react to errors.

```
 Try
      For Each locat In locations

         My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(locat, copyTO, True)

      Next
Catch ex As IOException
    ' The file was in use, so it cannot be copied
    'Throw an error or do what you want.
End Try
```

Documentation for Try...Catch [Documentation: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)

Comment: Didnt work... 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: It did work if it threw that error. It's telling you what the problem is but it cannot continue with that error. If it's throwing that error then you need to take a look at this post on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576196/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-occurred-in

But you should keep that try...catch in there for the other errors.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know if the file is locked is readonly until you try to copy it. Because between the time you check the file and try to copy it, the state might changed.

When you copy the file, keep a log of each error but continue the copy process. At the end, show a log of all the errors.

```
For Each locat In locations
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(locat, copyTO, True)
    Catch ex As IOException
        ' Log the error and the file and display it later
    End Try
Next
```